# Parsing XML Returned By ZoHo CRM API

Tags: php, xml, xpath, zoho

This is a sample of the XML returned from ZoHo CRM API. I need to parse out all of the data to insert into a database. Those records that are "Parents" do not have a Parent Account ID or Parent Account Name (see example row 2). This causes Undefined offset: errors at those lines. I am at a loss as to why...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<response uri="/crm/private/xml/Accounts/getRecords">  
<Accounts>
<row no="1">
<FL val="ACCOUNTID">123456789</FL>
<FL val="Account Name"><![CDATA[My Account Center]]></FL>
<FL val="PARENTACCOUNTID">234567891</FL>
<FL val="Parent Account"><![CDATA[Global Corp]]></FL>
<FL val="Shipping State"><![CDATA[IN]]></FL>
<FL val="Account Status"><![CDATA[Active Account]]></FL>
</row>
<row no="2">
<FL val="ACCOUNTID">234567891</FL>
<FL val="Account Name"><![CDATA[Global Corp]]></FL>
<FL val="Shipping State"><![CDATA[IN]]></FL>
<FL val="Account Status"><![CDATA[Active Account]]></FL>
</row>
</Accounts>
</response>
```

I can access all of the desired nodes using XPATH:

```
$accounts = $XML->xpath('/response/result/Accounts/row/FL[@val="ACCOUNTID"]');
$acctName = $XML->xpath('/response/result/Accounts/row/FL[@val="Account Name"]');
$pAcctID = $XML->xpath('/response/result/Accounts/row/FL[@val="PARENTACCOUNTID"]');
$pAcctName = $XML->xpath('/response/result/Accounts/row/FL[@val="Parent Account"]');
$state = $XML->xpath('/response/result/Accounts/row/FL[@val="Shipping State"]');
```

Then iterating through...

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $itemsTotal; $i++) {
$j = $i + 1;
echo "Counter: " . $i  . "<br/>";
echo "Record ID: " . $j . "<br/>";
echo "Account ID: " . $accounts[$i] . "<br/>";
echo "Account Name: " . $acctName[$i] . "<br/>";
echo "Location State: " . $state[$i] . "<br/>";
echo "Parent Account ID: " . $pAcctID[$i] . "<br/>";
echo "Parent Account Name: " . $pAcctName[$i] . "<br/>";
}
```

I have tried inserting this test in the loop:

```
if (isset($pAcctID[$i])) {
    $pACT = $pAcctID[$i];
    $pActName = $pAcctName[$i];
    echo "Parent Account ID: $pACT<br/>";
    echo "Parent Name: $pActName<br/>";
} else {
    echo "Is Parent Account<br/>";
    $pACT = "";
    $pActName = "";
}
```

Which does fine until it hits record 122/157 (shown as row 2 in the sample), then the Undefined Offset errors creep back in.

Updated... to look at this from a DOMDocument perspective.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load('zoho.xml');
$doc->saveXML();
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

foreach($xpath->query("//response/results/Accounts/row") as $data){
echo "Account ID is: " . $xpath->query(".//FL[@val='ACCOUNTID']",$data)->item(0)->nodeValue;
}
```

No data returned.

Comment: your `$pAcctID` and `$pAcctName` arrays contain less items than the others, and the indexes won't line up with your other variables.  Maybe it would be better to get all rows like this: `$rows = $XML->xpath('/response/result/Accounts/row');` and then iterate through `$itemsTotal`, and in each iteration, use a relative xpath query from the row to get the account id, name, parent and state etc.

Comment: Thanks, Keith! I've edited the original to update my findings.

Comment: in the XML you posted, `Accounts` is a child of `response`, but in your xpath, you are searching for a `results` child, maybe this is why there is no data returned?

Comment: if you change the expression in your `foreach` query to `$xpath->query("//response/Accounts/row") as $data`, then it looks like it should work :)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old now but there is a parameter you can send which should output all fields whether they're NULL or not, I generally ensure I'm passing :

```
&newFormat=2&selectColumns=All&version=2
```

Also I hope the following might help someone, it took me a while to figure out how to get the Zoho data back as a simple array :

```
public function getCustomerRecordsALL()
{
    $token = 'YourTokenHere'; //'$this->token;
    $url = "https://crm.zoho.com/crm/private/xml/Accounts/getRecords";
    $param= "authtoken=".$token."&scope=crmapi&newFormat=2&selectColumns=All&version=2&toIndex=200&fromIndex=-1&version=2";

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $param);

    // FIX THIS
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);        

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    // First deal with problem with Simple XML and CDATA
    $sxo = simplexml_load_string($result, null, LIBXML_NOCDATA);
    #$sxo = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents('testdata.txt'), null, LIBXML_NOCDATA); // TESTING ONLY

    $data = ($sxo->xpath('/response/result/Accounts/row'));

    //Set the variables you're expecting to capture
    $arrVariables = array("Account Name", "Address 1", "Address 2", "Address 3", "Email");
    $retArr = NULL;

    foreach($data as $row)                      // Iterate over all the results
    {
        foreach($arrVariables as $arrVar)       // Iterate through the variables we're looking for
        {
            $rowData = ($row->xpath('FL[@val="'.$arrVar.'"]'));
            @$arrReturn[$arrVar] = (string)$rowData[0][0];
        }
        $retArr[] = $arrReturn;
    }

    return $retArr;     
}

print_r(getCustomerRecordsALL());
```

The original poster could skip the first 20 lines or so and just load the XML from file.